# How to set msg.topic for Oracle nodes in Node-Red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

[image: node-red flow]
In the flow above I run query Q1 in DB1, process payload and form Q2 query based on the payload received and run it in DB2. Now I want to do some processing based on whether payload is received from DB2 or Q1 in node 'process'.How to set msg.topic for DB2 node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a change node or a another function node between `DB2` and the `process` function node to add/change the topic on the msg.

Also be aware that the `process` function node will always receive 2 independent messages, 1 from `Q1` and one from `DB2`. You will have to use the context to store state between them.